# second order DE using reduction of order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Any Hints / details on how to find a second solution for $$x^2y'' + xy' -4y=0?$$

$$y_1 = x^2 y_2$$

I need to use reduction of order
thanks

Comment: Find $y'_1$ and $y''_1$ and subs back in the ode.

Comment: are $y_2$ and $y_1$ solutions of ode?

Comment: do you substitute y(x)=u(x)*e^(x) back into equation?

Comment: He is looking for $y_2$ the second solution. The known solution is $y=x^2$.

Comment: if they are solution of the system,then their sum is also  solution,maybe substitution  $y_2$+$x^2*y_2$   makes  also some simplification,try to differentiate it

Comment: y1 and y2 are linearly independent solutions to the ODE

Comment: then substitution which i have posted will clarify things,is not it

Comment: Can you post the whole question? Reduction of order means that you already have a solution and you are looking for the second one. As I said already you have one solution $y=x^2$. You can check that by substituting back in the ode.

Comment: @javier: Is the $y_1$ solution you wrote correct? Is the $y_2$ there or not?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use [Ablel's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity) 
$$
\begin{vmatrix}y_1 & y_2\\ y_1' & y_2'\end{vmatrix}=C\exp\left(-\frac{a_1(x)}{a_0(x)}\right)
$$
to find $y_2$, then the general solution is their linear combination.

Answer (score 0):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269336/how-to-apply-reduction-of-order-to-find-a-2nd-linearly-independent-solution). You have one solution which is $y(x)=x^2$. To find the second one. Assume it has the form

> $$ y(x) = x^2 u(x) \implies y' =x^2 u'+2x u \implies y''=x^2u''+4x u'+2u. $$

Now, subs back in the ode

$$ x^2(x^2u''+4x u'+2u)+x (x^2 u'+2x u)-4x^2 u=0 . $$

You can take it from here to solve the new ode in $u(x)$. If you simplify the above you should get

> $$ xu''+5u'=0 \implies \frac{u''}{u'}=-\frac{5}{x}. $$

Comment: as far as I understand there is no explicit formula for the solution, just the relation between two

Comment: The question is about reduction of order and I explained in my comment above what it means.

Comment: But you did not recieved the confirmation from OP, that $y_1=x^2$

Comment: Not sure on how you simplify xu" + 5u'=0,

Comment: @javier: Assume $u'=w \implies u''=w'$, then solve the new ode in $w$ which you can solve by separation of variables.

Comment: Once you get xu"+5u'=0, you solve for u=C1x + c2x ?

Comment: @javier: See what I added.

Comment: Mhenni thanks for the help,

Comment: @javier: you got the answer? You are welcome

Comment: Mhenni , I did the integration by using separable variables but I'm not getting the right result. the solution should be y2=x^2(C1/x^4)=c1/x^2

Comment: @javier: Yes, that's right. Good job.

Comment: Mhenni,did you had to integrate twice to get the result?

Comment: I'm not there yet

Comment: @javier: Yes, that's correct. You already got the second solution. Your general solution of the ode should be $y(x)=Ax^2+\frac{B}{x^2}$.