# Question on Reduction of Order for Second Linear DEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone explain how the method of reduction of order can be used to explain the solution of second linear ODEs with repeated roots in the form of:
$$
ax^2 y'' + bxy' +cy = 0 ?
$$

I know that if there is a repeated root, then one solution is $y(x)=x^{r_1}$. Also, the method of reduction of order essentially states that there is a function $u$ by which the first solution can be multiplied in order to arrive at a second solution, however, I find myself struggling with a purely proof-based example using only a, b, and c.

With a numerically based example, I have no problem, but symbolically that appears to be were I am struggling.

Could anyone clue me in?

Many thanks.

Comment: So if this question had been posed with some specific numbers instead of $a,$ $b,$ and $c,$ you could take it from there? I recall that some students found the distinction between parameters ($a, b, c$ in this case) and variables (here, $x, y$) confusing--is that possibly your difficulty?

Comment: @TheColonel: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600129/second-order-de-using-reduction-of-order).

Comment: @DavidK - I absolutely know how to go about solving it numerically.  Yes, it appears to be the parameters that I am confused about.

Comment: It might be a helpful exercise to draw a line down the middle of a sheet of paper, dividing the page into two columns. In the left column, replace $a, b,$ and $c$ with specific numbers such as $2, 3,$ and $4,$ and solve the equation. Then, in the right column, write the original equation and try to follow exactly the same steps as in the left column. I've done this sometimes after working out some numeric problem (usually not an ODE, but similar principles apply), then realizing I'm going to have to do the same thing several times in the future, just with different numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is what you are looking for, but if not please comment.

We can rewrite the DE as:

$$x^2y''+axy'+by=0$$

If $y_1$ is a solution to the DE, then we will look for a second solution of the form $y_2=y_1v$.

$$y_2'=y_1'v+y_1v'  $$
$$y_2''=y_1''v+2y_1'v'+y_1v''$$

Plugging these equations into the original DE we find:

$$x^2y_1''v+2x^2y_1'v'+x^2y_1v''+axy_1'v+axy_1v'+by_1v=0  $$

Now, because $y_1$ is itself a solution, the first, fourth, and last terms are summed to $0$.  So we are left with:
$$x^2y_1v''+2x^2y_1'v'+axy_1v'=0  $$

Let's now make the following substitutions $u=v'$, and $y_1=x^r$.
$$x^{r+2}u'+2rx^{r+1}u+ax^{r+1}u=0   $$
$$u'+\frac{2r+a}{x}u=0  $$

Do you see how to proceed from here?

**EDIT**

Our characteristic equation is $r^2+(a-1)r+b=0$.  Since we have repeated roots, the derivative of the characteristic equation must be zero as the roots occur at the same place on the $r$ axis.  Thus,

$$2r+a-1=0$$
$$2r+a=1$$

Now, just substitute this into that last differential equation, and solve for $u$.  Then integrate again to find $v$. Also, you should arrive at $u=1/x$ and $v=\ln x$.

Comment: Procedurally I know absolutely how to go about performing the method of reduction of order, it was the proof aspect of it which was challenging.

Basically integrating the last line of your expression should lead to the second solution being

$$
c_{1} + c_{2}ln(x)
$$

Comment: Do you mean something like a rigorous proof on why we are allowed to use the reduction of order technique?

Comment: Well using one in the case of a second linear DE with repeated roots and showing how it arrives at the second solution I mentioned.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I will edit the answer.

Comment: I guess the only question I have remaining is what happened to the C term in the new characteristic equation?

Comment: What if the characteristic equation is ar(r-1) + br + c?

Comment: Rewrite the original equation in the form I wrote. Then expand. This will give you the same equation as the one in the answer. I don't know what you are saying in regards to the $c$. There is not a $c$ anywhere in the answer.

Comment: I was referring to the c in the characteristic equation
$$
ar(r-1) +br +c
$$
I guess I have trouble understanding how you can rewrite the DE in the form you suggested.